# jQuery change fadeOut time loader screen

Tags: jquery

i have problem with jQuery function. I will put code first, then will explain where is problem.

*HTML Page:*

```
<div id="load"></div>
```

*JavaScript Page:*

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  "use strict";

  $("#load").fadeOut( 200, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
```

Okay, when i change `200` to `3000` that is delay time from 0.2s to 3s time. But when i run page, loading is same. I'm i put wrong somethign? I just wanted to loader time is 3 seconds not 0,2 if am right.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#load").fadeOut( 3000, function() {
     setTimeout($(this).remove(), 1000);
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value

Comment: Thanks. And i dont get why this question is with ( -2 ) votes?